# Firestore - arrayRemove and arrayUnion at same time?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to do something like this.

```
return await this.fooCol.doc(id).update({
  images: firebase.default.firestore.FieldValue
    .arrayRemove(...data.removedImages).arrayUnion(...data.addedImages),
}); //doesnt work
```

I'm current doing this where I use `Promise.all()`

```
return await Promise.all([
  this.fooCol.doc(id).update({
    images: firebase.default.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(
      ...data.removedImages
    ),
  }),
  this.fooCol.doc(id).update({
    images: firebase.default.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(...imageUrls),
  }),
]);
```

**But is there any other way than using `Promise.all()`?**

Comment: If you want to do it with one set, then you'll have to pull down `images`, create the updated state, then set that in the db. If it's a huge list, or you don't want to do that for some reason, I don't see anything wrong with your two step approach.

Comment: That looks like the start of a great answer @windowsill :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to pull down the whole array and construct a new one, then it's safest to do this in a batch of 2 operations. Using Web SDK v9 syntax:

```
const batch = writeBatch(db);
batch.update(doc(db, 'path'), {images: arrayRemove(...data.removedImages)});
batch.update(doc(db, 'path'), {images: arrayUnion(...imageUrls)});
await batch.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Unfortunately I've found that using `arrayRemove()` in a batch to remove an object will not cause the full batch operation to fail when the the `arrayRemove()` operation in the batch fails (e.g. if the object has been updated on the server and is no longer an exact match). From the [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions), I'd expect a batch to fail if any operation within the batch fails, but that doesn't seem to be the case with `arrayRemove()`.

Comment: I believe `arrayRemove()` is a noop if you pass in an item the doesn't exist. Are you expecting the operation fail?

Comment: Yes--I was hoping that the batch operation would fail if the object passed to `arrayRemove()` does not match and fails to remove the object.  Otherwise if the array has been modified on the server (e.g. by another user), the `arrayUnion()` operation will end up creating two versions of the object in different states.  If the batch would fail on a failed `arrayRemove()` operation, it would solve that problem and alleviate the need to pull down the whole array.  Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: The problem you're facing is that `arrayRemove()` doesn't fail (i.e. doesn't throw an exception) when it tries to remove an item that doesn't exist, so the batch doesn't fail either. What you can probably do is write a firestore rule that rejects the operation if the number of items changes in the operation. Look at the `get()` and `getAfter()` functions in firestore rules. That together with the batch operation should get you what you want.

Comment: That sounds like an excellent solution. I'll dig into that.  Thanks!

Comment: @ericboles I tested your use case with a Firestore Rule and it was quite simple. I didn't need to use `get()` and `getAfter()`. Assuming your field name is `images`, it was as simple as adding this Firestore Rule: `allow update: if request.resource.data.images.size() == resource.data.images.size();`. That together with the batch example I provided above will ensure that the batch only succeeds if it removes and adds the same number of items.